# Unable to access the OpenStack VM

Tags: virtualization, remote-access

I installed microopenstack and unable to access the VM from my Laptop.
Network IP's are:
two builtin OpenStack network and my local network 192.168.18.0.

ALI

Comment: Oh was long time ago I did OpenStack,  can you provide some more info? Like;   Any error message?  Screenshot? Log?   Version of Ubuntu(If it is, hopefully it is Ubuntu ;)  )   Best Wishes.

Comment: No error, But how I can access this. My local WiFi network unable to ping the OpenStack network. I also using VMware and when I create the VM it will assign my local IP to newly-created VM and I can easily access this.